# how should i eliminate button shrinkage?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm looking for the right way of displaying buttons around an input field in one row, and avoid (if possible) the use the "width" attribute. I want the buttons and field to line up in a fixed width and position even as the value (that the user chooses from the drop down) change

```
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">             
                          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-6">                            
                                <form class="form-inline">
                                         <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 40px;">

                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn-block" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                                  <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:blue"></i> United States <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
                                                                    <li><a href="#"><strong>United States</strong></a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                 </div>         
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                              USD <span class="caret"></span>
                                                              </button>
                                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
                                                                    <li><a href="#"><strong>USD</strong></a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">EUR</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="amountnum"> </label>
                                            <input style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="amountnum" placeholder="number" value="10">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                              1 month <span class="caret"></span>
                                                              </button>
                                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
                                                                    <li><a href="#">1 Weeks</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#">2 Weeks</a></li>
                                                                    <li><a href="#"><strong>1 month</strong></a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                </form>
                          </div>                
                          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:  `https://jsfiddle.net/drorm/k43kyfpw/`

when the screen opens, make the left pane narrower to see the buttons line up (instead of falling dropping to separate rows)

Suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Give your inputs and buttons a percentage width and not a fixed pixel width.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS style

```
.navbar-form,.form-inline {
  display: flex;
}
```

The use of `flex` (or `inline-flex`) is quite powerful. Combine with the css `flex` property on items to control the growth and shrinking of controls.

Google "CSS flex" for more.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/